# Como capturar o valor de um select criado dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, select

(Sei que ja existe uma discussao parecida, mas nao me ajudou.)

O meu objetivo é o seguinte:

- caso escolha 'credito' ou 'carne', abre uma div com as opçoes de parcelamento.
- nessa div é criado um select, que recebe o valor da compra e deve calcular a taxa em cada opção de parcelamento.
- a minha ideia era pegar a quantidade de parcelas (value do select) e mandar pra minha funçao 'calTaxa' junto do valor total, assim ele retornaria o valor da parcela de acordo com quantas vezes foi parcelado.
- O problema é que, como o select só é criado ao clicar nas funcoes 'credito' e 'carne', nao consigo capturar o value pra enviar pra função.

HTML:

```
<div class="payment-method-installment"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('.payment-method-installment').html
    ( '<span>Valor total: R$' + 245 + '</span>' +
      '<div> <span>Parcelas: </span>' +
        '<select id="select-parc">' +
          '<option value="1"> 1x de R$ ' + calTaxa($('#select-parc option:selected').val(), soma) + ' </option>'+ 
        '</select> </div>' +
     '</div>');
```

O '`$('#select-parc option:selected').val()`' retorna 'undefined'. É possivel capturar o value do select selecionado durante a sua criação? Caso nao, qual seria a melhor alternativa?

Comment: É possível se na hora de executar o código citado o elemento existir na página. Provavelmente está retornando undefined pq ele nao existe.

Comment: nesse caso, eu poderia fazer algo do tipo: criar o select com os 'options' com os values, e em seguida editar o texto do option pra mostrar as taxas?

Answer (score 0):

Essa sua pergunta não faz muito sentido. Talvez você possa reformulá-la.

Agora, se o valor de 1x é escrito diretamente na string, voce não precisa pegar o valor do select, basta passar diretamente para o `calTaxa(1, soma);`. Agora, se isso for um array, e listará dinamicamente, você pode passar o index do array para o `calTaxa(index + 1, soma);`.

Mais um detalhe. Considere mudar o nome da função para `calculaTaxa`. Não tem motivos para diminuir o nome de uma função para economizar milisegundos de digitação.

Comment: Ola Allef, eu sou novo por aqui, me desculpa kk.
A questao é que esse '1' que vou passar na função, é o usuario que vai selecionar no select, ja que ele pode selecionar de 1 a 10, e a taxa varia de acordo com o numero. Eu coloquei somente uma linha do option pra nao ficar muito grande